# Why does to_a and to_ary behave differently in subclasses of Array?

Tags: ruby, duck-typing

If you have a subclass X of Array, then doing `X#to_a` returns an array object, while doing `X#to_ary` returns an x object.

While I understand that `to_a` means "I can be changed into an array", while `to_ary` means "I behave like an array", I don't understand why the former implements a change of class while the latter doesn't.

Also, isn't returning a subclass of Array sufficient for `to_a`, under the Liskov Substitution Principle?

Comment: For what it's worth, I too think it's dumb that calling to_a on a  subclass of an Array would change the class to an Array, when it *already is* an Array (is_a?(Array) would return true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is "because that's the way it's defined to be" sufficient?

> #### [`to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-to_a)
>
> Returns `self`. If called on a subclass of `Array`, converts the receiver to an `Array` object.

> #### [`to_ary`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-to_ary)
>
> Returns `self`.

Probably not, so here we go into the rabbit hole.

Beyond the fact that the documentation definitively states that this is the way it is, the reasoning is perhaps only truly answerable by Matz, et al.

Digging around though it would seem that [`to_ary` is used when implicit type conversions occur](http://ruby.runpaint.org/variables#fn-3). Its use for implicit conversions seems to be echoed in [this feature request](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4917) as well. In other words, if an object responds to `to_ary`, then it should be treated as an `Array`, and it is used in this way internally. Thus `to_a` would be for when you (explicitly) want an `Array` and not some subclass.

Yes, returning a subclass would still satisfy LSP (assuming the subclass does not decide to radically change the behavior of `Array` such that it wouldn't be), but the principle only states that a subclass *may* be substituted for its base class, not that it needs to be. I'm not really sure that matter here anyway, though, since you're calling `to_a` your explicitly asking for a different object (to go along with the reasoning about implicit conversions above) and thus you're saying you don't want a substitute object type.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, the implicit conversions are automatically called by the interpreter, and they are intended to only convert things that are very much like the type that was required but not found.

The *explicit* conversions, however, can be called on disparate types as long as there is some way to get from point a to point b, even if that involves some sort of polar route or a detour.

So you simply have more freedom for a leap with to_a, but I agree that it seems like *X* should be good enough.